# Which licence to use when writing a program based on an existing one?

Tags: licensing

Say program A is licensed under GNU GPL 2.0. I write a new program (B) which is heavily inspired by A. Both do pretty much the same thing with some small differences (B has a couple of old features removed and a new one added) and they look almost the same.

The only meaningful differences are that B has been rewritten in a different language and had a general code cleanup. But in general, the way the program works is the same as the original.

Does B have to be licensed under GNU GPL 2.0 too? Or since it's not a direct copy of the original it can use any licence I want?

Of course the original project will be mentioned in the README either way.

Comment: I feel this is pretty much answered by [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10767/at-what-point-is-software-different-enough-to-exclude-bsd-license-notice) but it may be worth trying to turn this into a canonical question and answer.

Comment: See also this near (98%)-duplicate: [If I translate/port a repository from one programming language to another, do I need to use the license file (Github) from that original project?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6699/if-i-translate-port-a-repository-from-one-programming-language-to-another-do-i)

Comment: For GPL, though, you can't sublicense like you can with the permissive licenses mentioned in the linked questions (MIT, BSD). It means that your "new project" program B (which is a translation of program A) must still remain all GPL in practice, at least for all the parts that were translated from the old program. Does that difference warrant a new Answer for this one?